# How to handle an exception 500 error message in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, spartacus-storefront

I am having difficulties figuring out how to add a custom 500 error message for an exception.

When the response has the status of Internal Server Error, I receive a backend response that looks like this:

```
errors: [
    0: {
      errorCode: null
      exceptionMessage: null
      language: null
      message: "BAPIException with type: E id:  messageNumber: 000 message: Keine Barcodedaten gefunden (ZPORH_BARCODELISTE_CSV)"
      position: null
      reason: null
      subject: null
      subjectType: null,
      type: "BWPErpIntegrationBapiError"
    }
]
```

My internal server handler looks like this so far:

```
responseStatus = HttpResponseStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

  // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
  handleError(_request: HttpRequest<any>, response: HttpErrorResponse): void {
    if (response.status === this.responseStatus) {
      // console.log(response.error);
      if (response.error?.type === 'BWPErpIntegrationBapiError') {
        this.globalMessageService.add(
          response.error?.message,
          GlobalMessageType.MSG_TYPE_ERROR
        );
      } else {
        // console.log(response.status);

        this.globalMessageService.add(
          { key: 'httpHandlers.internalServerError' },
          GlobalMessageType.MSG_TYPE_ERROR
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem I am facing is that the response I get from the backend is not the same as the `HttpErrorResponse` from Angular, and I do not know how to approach this problem.
I tried to extend the HttpErrorResponse and add an `errors` property that has that array with values and create an interceptor for it but console logging the response.errors[0] was always null.

Also the way I get this `BWPErpIntegrationBapiError` exception is by trying to download and CSV that also has a `response.error` value of `Blob`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution by parsing the blob data, I will only need to add another if statement for when there is no Blob type data.

```
 responseStatus = HttpResponseStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

  // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
  handleError(_request: HttpRequest<any>, response: any): void {
    if (response.status === this.responseStatus) {
      if (response.error instanceof Blob) {
        response.error.text().then(text => {
          const errors = JSON.parse(text).errors;
          console.log(errors);

          if (errors[0].type === 'BWPErpIntegrationBapiError') {
            this.globalMessageService.add(
              errors[0].message,
              GlobalMessageType.MSG_TYPE_ERROR
            );
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.globalMessageService.add(
          { key: 'httpHandlers.internalServerError' },
          GlobalMessageType.MSG_TYPE_ERROR
        );
      }
    }
  }
```